# Querying lists in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a collection of documents in Elasticsearch.  Each document has a "categories" field, which is an ordered list, from most general to most specific, of the names of the categories that this document is in.  The category hierarchy is a taxonomy (each category has only one parent) but names of the categories overlap.  The full category chain, from the root, is the only sure way to identify the category that a document is in.

For example, one document could have a categories field:

```
["Science", "Biology", "Journal"]
```

And another could have:

```
["Science", "Astronomy", "Journal"]
```

The questions:

1) How can I aggregate documents into their unique categories?  I have the "categories" field mapped as not-analyzed, but still, a simple term aggregation will group both of the documents above together in the "Journal" bucket. Is there a way to aggregate by position in a list, or aggregate only terms in a particular position in a list?

2) Given a unique category, as identified by its path, how do I filter documents in the category?  Is there a way to filter according to position in list?

Comment: try to update with your schema so we can help you with the query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. See [multivalue fields](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html#_multivalue_fields)

> However, arrays are indexed—made searchable—as multivalue fields, which are unordered. At search time, you can’t refer to “the first element” or “the last element.” Rather, think of an array as a bag of values.

What you can do, is using nested objects, or more simple just write the path down in one field, and index it analyzed and not analyzed.

```
{"categories":"Science Biology Journal"}
```

Now you can search on it using a range of filters and queries. For example:

- Term (not analyzed): if you want the exact path
- String Query: if you want one or more categories
- ...